# Entity Framework Code First double relation to same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a `Page` class that is to be associated with similar pages. Each association has additional information about the association. This is the class that has been defined as the representation of a `Page`.

```
public class Page {
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Page")]
    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}
```

Each page has can be associated with any number of other pages. This is to be defined as a source and a target page. I do not mind if the association is unidirectional or bidirectional, either will be justified in my particular scenario (I prefer bidirectional associations, tough). This is the association class..

```
public class Association {
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public virtual int PageId { get; protected set; } // SOURCE
    [Required]
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; } // SOURCE
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int TargetId { get; protected set; } // TARGET
    [Required]
    public virtual Page Target { get; set; } // TARGET
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public virtual string InformationAboutTheAssociation { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the following context ...

```
public class DbCtx : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Association> Associations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

And the issue is that SQL Express is complaining about possible cyclic references (which is not the case, but it is over-protective). How do I solve the scheme that is generated to accept the described scenario?

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Associations_dbo.Pages_TargetId' on table 'Associations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Either. I use 5.0 now, but can use 4.3 as well.

Comment: Use 5.0. It has improvements in the speed department.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RESPONSE**

Do what the error tells you.
**Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION**. Since you have two foreign keys to the same entity, and model first (probably) inserts by default `on delete cascade`, you must disable this, because when a page is deleted, the association will try to be deleted by the first foreign key but will fail because of the second foreign key.

**Modify 3**

```
public class DbCtx : DbContext {
public DbSet<Association> Associations { get; set; }
public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Association>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Page)
            .WithMany(x => x.Associations)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

}

I think this should work.

**Deleting a Page entity**

Because you don't have `on delete cascade` on the Association if you try and delete a Page it will fail if you have Association entities that depend on the Page entity you want to delete.

*So when you want to delete a Page you must first delete all the associations referencing the Page*. You have a foreign constraint (two of them actually) from the Association to the Page. Use only one of them and be consistent (either Page or Target).

Since you have asked this question I can only conclude you don't really know how SQL works so it is better if you also read a book about designing a database and using SQL.

---

I haven't used code first in EF but considering an Entity Relation diagram, Page has "1 to many" with Association and Association has two "1 to 1" with Page.

*Isn't this cyclic because it seems like and it's a bad design.*

Normalize the database.

If you would design the database (database first), you wouldn't need the relation "1 to many" between the Page and Association because you already have the relation "1 to 1" (two of them) from Association to Page.
So if you want to look for a specific association knowing the pagId you can have a `select * from association where pageId or targetId = the id you are looking for`.

If you would use EF with database first, you would have a back reference from page to association (what you are trying to do here) but not in the actual Entity Relation model of the database itself. They are virtual references.

**EDIT:**

I reread the question and the problem is the second reference from the Association to the Page. It is strange since the database first works fine with this case.

I will look into it.

Comment: Exactly how would you normalize a relational model of a tree hierarchy (or, in this case, a directed graph) without the entity having a reference to itself? Any "one to many" relation is really just the inverse of a "one to one" or "many to one" relationship, which your proposed change has. One of the main advantages of using ORM is that these become navigable intuitively and are captured explicitly in your model classes, without having to deal with "virtual references".

Comment: You have to be more specific about the tree hierarchy. The parent entity does not need to have a reference to the child entity (only the child has a foreign key to the parent). You can have entities reference itself (because of the design)and it does not mean it's cyclic but in this case the cyclic warning seems to be correct because you ahve e entities referring each other.

Comment: Even if I use ORM (and I use it a lot) I still prefer to design my database by hand and then use EF database first. The references back and forth are added automatically and are virtually because they don't reside in the database scheme. Under the hood a back reference is just a `select by primary key`  that you don't write.

Comment: Sorry, how is an entity referencing itself any less cyclic than doing so indirectly. (Which you *have* to do if you want to annotate the edges in the tree/graph.) Also, the one-to-many side of the relationship is strictly an ORM feature. In the SQL, generated or hand-written, the parent entity won't reference the child entities, if only because that's not even possible. If you read the OP carefully, you'll notice that the error is on a foreign key in the "Associations" table.

Comment: Just in case my point got lost: The solution you're proposing will be *substantially the same SQL schema* as the one that Entity Framework will generate for the OP's model.

Comment: I didn't said the parent has a reference to the child. I don't understand what you mean by *Also, the one-to-many side of the relationship is strictly an ORM feature*. In SQL 1-to-many is a type of relationship.

Comment: My phrasing was wrong, what I meant to say is that the one-to-many relationship being expressed on the "one" side is an ORM feature. I still don't think you can model an annotated graph as the user wants with the entity representing the edge (`Association`) having two one-to-one relationship. In your model, how could the "source" page have multiple "targets" if the relationships are all one-to-one? (Preferrably, edit the model you have in mind into your question so we don't need to use prose.)

Comment: The Association table is there to make connections between different pages (source and target). This means the Page id attribute must already exist before a new row is inserted in the Association. Now an association can not exist without 2 pages (src and target) but a page can exist without having an association. Because of this, you don't need 1-to-many between page and association. It's a useless relation that does nothing. You can do all the queries that you want with those two 1-to-1.

Comment: You're confused about what a one-to-one relationship means then. A one-to-one relationship from `Association` to "source" Page means that a page can only be the source for one association. A relationship from `Association` to source `Page` without a `UNIQUE` constraint on it is a one-to-many relationship. Which, as I said several times, is present in the ORM model *for convenience*, because it generates the queries you mention for you.

Comment: How many databases have you designed using E/R models ? I know what the relationships mean. But it seems we don;t understand each other. Anyway, I know why he gets the error.

Comment: Nice discussion. I've used the OnModelCreating idea by amb and modified it to suit the relation as described for a unidirectional relation. The generated scheme is perfect, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I just noticed that it is no longer possible to delete Page. Normally, the references to it would be deleted by cascade and this is the situation I want. Right now, it will tell me it cannot delete the Page because of an Association.

Comment: @Roel van Uden It is normal since you don't have `on delete cascade` on the Association. When you want to delete a Page you must first delete all the associations referencing the Page. You have a foreign constraint (two of them actually) from the Association to the Page. Use only one of them and be consistent (either Page or Target).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I guess I can't get around that :)

Comment: You are welcome but you should really read a book about how SQL works and also about designing a database (although you usually find them in the same book).